# Extract properties associated with classes from RDF file

Tags: semantics, rdf, dotnetrdf

I  have written my code to extract classes and Subclasses from my RDF file.. This is the code.. I am using dotNetRDf library..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using VDS.RDF;
using VDS.RDF.Ontology;
using VDS.RDF.Parsing;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    //
        OntologyGraph g = new OntologyGraph();
        FileLoader.Load(g, "D:\\SBIRS.owl");
        OntologyClass someClass = g.CreateOntologyClass(new    
        Uri("http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2012/0/SBIRS.owl#Shape"));

                  //Write out Super Classes

        foreach (OntologyClass c in someClass.SuperClasses)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Super Class: " + c.Resource.ToString());
        }
        //Write out Sub Classes



        foreach (OntologyClass c in someClass.SubClasses)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Sub Class: " + c.Resource.ToString());
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

}

But  now i want to extract the properties associated with classes.. I tried to use OntologyProperty class but was not able to get desired output

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `extract the properties associated with the classes`?

This could mean any number of things, do you mean simply find the properties which have that class as a domain/range?

You can't do this using the Ontology API which is just a wrapper around the underlying APIs but you can use the lower level API like so:

```
//Assuming you've already set up your Graph and Class as above...

//Find properties who have this class as a domain
INode domain = g.CreateUriNode(new Uri(NamespaceMapper.RDFS + "domain"));
IEnumerable<OntologyProperty> ps = g.GetTriplesWithPredicateObject(domain, someClass).Select(t => new OntologyProperty(t.Subject, g));

//Now iterate over ps and do what you want with the properties
```

Equally you could do the same things with `rdfs:range` to get properties which have the class as a range